# WebGL FBO (real-time drawing)

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to translate this example from Three.js - https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/PZmpEM
to pure WebGL. I experimented a lot with the code, I think there is an error in texture baking, but my attempts are unsuccessful, if not difficult, please!

WebGL example

```js
let a_Position, u_Mouse, u_Sampler, u_Resolution;

const position = {
  screenRect: null,
  xyz: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  mouseDown: false,
};

function main() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

  const program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  const tick = function() {
    render(gl, canvas, fbo, plane);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick, canvas);
  };
  
  a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
  u_Mouse = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_mouse');
  u_Resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_resolution');
  u_Sampler = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_sampler');

  const fbo = [initFramebufferObject(gl), initFramebufferObject(gl)];
  const plane = initVertexBuffersForPlane(gl);
  tick();
}

let src = 0, dst = 1, t;
function render(gl, canvas, fbo, plane) {
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[dst]);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
  drawTexture(gl, gl.program, plane, fbo[src].texture);

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawTexture(gl, gl.program, plane, fbo[dst].texture);

  t = src;
  src = dst;
  dst = t;
}

function drawTexture(gl, program, o, texture) {
  gl.uniform3f(u_Mouse, ...position.xyz);
  gl.uniform2f(u_Resolution, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  initAttributeVariable(gl, a_Position, o.vertexBuffer);

  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, o.indexBuffer);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, o.numIndices, o.indexBuffer.type, 0);
}

function initAttributeVariable(gl, a_attribute, buffer) {
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_attribute, buffer.num, buffer.type, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_attribute);
}

function initFramebufferObject(gl) {
  const framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer(), texture = gl.createTexture();

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 255]));
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


  framebuffer.texture = texture;

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

  return framebuffer;
}

function initVertexBuffersForPlane(gl) {
  const vertices = new Float32Array([1.0, 1.0, 0.0,  -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,  -1.0,-1.0, 0.0,   1.0,-1.0, 0.0]);

  const texCoords = new Float32Array([1.0, 1.0,   0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0]);

  const indices = new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2,   0, 2, 3]);

  const o = {};

  o.vertexBuffer = initArrayBufferForLaterUse(gl, vertices, 3, gl.FLOAT);
  o.indexBuffer = initElementArrayBufferForLaterUse(gl, indices, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE);

  o.numIndices = indices.length;

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

  return o;
}

function initArrayBufferForLaterUse(gl, data, num, type) {
  const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  buffer.num = num;
  buffer.type = type;
  return buffer;
}

function initElementArrayBufferForLaterUse(gl, data, type) {
  const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  buffer.type = type;
  return buffer;
}
  
function mouseHandlers() {
  function getPosition(e) { 
   const x = e.clientX, y = window.innerHeight - e.clientY, z = 0.05;
   position.xyz = [x, y, z];
  }

  function getRect() {
     position.screnRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  }

  function mouseDown(e) {
     position.mouseDown = true;
     getPosition(e);
  }

  function move(e) {
     if (position.mouseDown) getPosition(e); 
     else return; 
  }

  function up() {
     position.mouseDown = false;
  }

  getRect();
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown); 
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', move); 
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', up); 
 }
   
mouseHandlers();
main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script  id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
  attribute vec4 a_position;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = a_position;
  }
</script>

<script  id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;

  uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
  uniform vec2 u_resolution;
  uniform vec3 u_mouse;

  void main() {
     vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler, uv);
     float dist = distance(u_mouse.xy, gl_FragCoord.xy);
     gl_FragColor.rgb += u_mouse.z * max(15.0-dist,0.0);
     //gl_FragColor.gb += 0.01; /* testing FBO */
  }
</script>

<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```

So I have a result after moving the mouse but something is wrong:

[image: 1]

It should be:

[image: 2]

Comment: Please add a  [Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to the question.

Comment: @Stenvis, linking to your code is off topic. Put your code in the question itself.  There are 1000s of examples of webgl questions with [working snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in them. Your code is also using some pretty bad patterns. Consider some [other tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: sorry for the mess! I will be very happy with your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obvious mistake when you create the texture objects for the frambuffer.

If you do not generate [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) (by `gl.generateMipmap`), then it is important to set `gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`. Since the default filter is `gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` the texture would be mipmap incomplete, if you don't change the minifying function to `gl.NEAREST` or `gl.LINEAR`:

```js
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
```

See further [OpenGL ES 2.0 Full Specification - 3.7.10 Texture Completeness](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf#page=93&zoom=100,168,173).

---

I recommend to check the completeness of the framebuffer:

```js
if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    // [...]
}
```

---

The size of the frame buffer textures has to be a power of 2 (WebGL 1.0). Create framebuffers with a fixed size (e.g. 1024x1024):

```js
framebuffer.size = [1024, 1024];
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, ...framebuffer.size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(tblack));
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

framebuffer.texture = texture;
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    alert("incomplete frambuffer");
}
```

---

Ensure that the uniforms are set correctly. Set the resolution (`u_resolution`) dependent on the size of the framebuffer. The position of the mouse (`u_mouse`) has to be relative to the size of the framebuffer:

```py
function drawTexture(gl, program, o, texture, resolution) {
    const mx = position.xyz[0] * resolution[0] / canvas.width;
    const my = position.xyz[1] * resolution[1] / canvas.height;
    gl.uniform3f(u_Mouse, mx, my, position.xyz[2]);
    gl.uniform2f(u_Resolution, resolution[0], resolution[1]);

    initAttributeVariable(gl, a_Position, o.vertexBuffer);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, o.indexBuffer);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, o.numIndices, o.indexBuffer.type, 0);
}
```

Set the viewport rectangle when you switch the current frame buffer

```js
let src = 0, dst = 1, t;
function render(gl, canvas, fbo, plane) {
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[dst]);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, ...fbo[dst].size);
    drawTexture(gl, gl.program, plane, fbo[src].texture, fbo[src].size);

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawTexture(gl, gl.program, plane, fbo[dst].texture, [canvas.width, canvas.height]);

    t = src;
    src = dst;
    dst = t;
}
```

---

See the example, where the computation of the distance to the mouse is scaled, by the ration of the canvas resoultuion and the framebuffer:

```js
let a_Position, u_Mouse, u_Sampler;

const position = {
  screenRect: null,
  xyz: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
  mouseDown: false,
};

function main() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

  const program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  const tick = function() {
    render(gl, canvas, fbo, plane);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick, canvas);
  };
  
  a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
  u_Mouse = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_mouse');
  u_Sampler = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_sampler');
  u_Resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_resolution');
  u_CanvasSize = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_canvasSize');

  const fbo = [initFramebufferObject(gl), initFramebufferObject(gl)];
  const plane = initVertexBuffersForPlane(gl);
  tick();
}

let src = 0, dst = 1, t;
function render(gl, canvas, fbo, plane) {
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[dst]);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, ...fbo[dst].size);
    drawTexture(gl, gl.program, plane, fbo[src].texture, fbo[src].size);

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawTexture(gl, gl.program, plane, fbo[dst].texture, [canvas.width, canvas.height]);

    t = src;
    src = dst;
    dst = t;
}

function drawTexture(gl, program, o, texture, resolution) {
    const mx = position.xyz[0] * resolution[0] / canvas.width;
    const my = position.xyz[1] * resolution[1] / canvas.height;
    gl.uniform3f(u_Mouse, mx, my, position.xyz[2]);
    gl.uniform2f(u_Resolution, resolution[0], resolution[1]);
    gl.uniform2f(u_CanvasSize, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    initAttributeVariable(gl, a_Position, o.vertexBuffer);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, o.indexBuffer);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, o.numIndices, o.indexBuffer.type, 0);
}

function initAttributeVariable(gl, a_attribute, buffer) {
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_attribute, buffer.num, buffer.type, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_attribute);
}

function initFramebufferObject(gl) {
    let framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer(), texture = gl.createTexture();

    framebuffer.size = [1024, 1024];
    let tblack = []
    for (let i= 0; i < framebuffer.size[0]*framebuffer.size[1]; i ++) tblack.push(0, 0, 0, 255);
    
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, ...framebuffer.size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(tblack));
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

    framebuffer.texture = texture;
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
      alert("incomplete frambuffer");
    }

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

    return framebuffer;
}

function initVertexBuffersForPlane(gl) {
  const vertices = new Float32Array([1.0, 1.0, 0.0,  -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,  -1.0,-1.0, 0.0,   1.0,-1.0, 0.0]);

  const texCoords = new Float32Array([1.0, 1.0,   0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0]);

  const indices = new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2,   0, 2, 3]);

  const o = {};

  o.vertexBuffer = initArrayBufferForLaterUse(gl, vertices, 3, gl.FLOAT);
  o.indexBuffer = initElementArrayBufferForLaterUse(gl, indices, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE);

  o.numIndices = indices.length;

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

  return o;
}

function initArrayBufferForLaterUse(gl, data, num, type) {
  const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  buffer.num = num;
  buffer.type = type;
  return buffer;
}

function initElementArrayBufferForLaterUse(gl, data, type) {
  const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  buffer.type = type;
  return buffer;
}
  
function mouseHandlers() {
  function getPosition(e) { 
   const x = e.clientX, y = window.innerHeight - e.clientY, z = 0.05;
   position.xyz = [x, y, z];
  }

  function getRect() {
     position.screnRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  }

  function mouseDown(e) {
     position.mouseDown = true;
     getPosition(e);
  }

  function move(e) {
     if (position.mouseDown) getPosition(e); 
     else return; 
  }

  function up() {
     position.mouseDown = false;
  }

  getRect();
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown); 
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', move); 
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', up); 
 }
   
mouseHandlers();
main();
```

```css
<style>
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
</style>
```

```html
<script  id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
  attribute vec4 a_position;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = a_position;
  }
</script>

<script  id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;

  uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
  uniform vec2 u_resolution;
  uniform vec2 u_canvasSize;
  uniform vec3 u_mouse;

  void main() {
     vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
     vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_sampler, uv);
     vec2 scale = u_canvasSize / u_resolution;
     float dist = distance(u_mouse.xy * scale, gl_FragCoord.xy * scale);
     float intensity = u_mouse.z * max(15.0-dist,0.0);
     gl_FragColor = texColor + vec4(vec3(intensity), 0.0);
  }
</script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```